# Android AsyncTask - onPostExecute not called (ProgressDialog)

Tags: android-asynctask, progressdialog, android

I have the following code:

```
try {
    res = new Utils(ubc_context).new DownloadCalendarTask().execute().get();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.v("downloadcalendar", "interruptedexecution : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    res = false;
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    Log.v("downloadcalendar", "executionexception : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    res = false;
}

Log.v("displaymenu", "A");
```

---

```
public class Utils {

private Context context;

public Utils(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public class DownloadCalendarTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public DownloadCalendarTask() {

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.v("preexecute", "A");
        dialog.setMessage("Loading calendar, please wait...");
        Log.v("preexecute", "B");
        dialog.show();
        Log.v("preexecute", "C");

    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // do some work here...
        return (Boolean) false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute() {
        Log.d("utils", "entered onpostexecute");
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

The first part of code is attached to an `onClick` listener for a button. When I click the button the button flashes (as it does to show it has been clicked), and then after about 8 seconds the Loading dialog appears but never finishes.

According to logcat, as soon as I click the button `onPreExecute` is executed as is `Dialog.show()`, so my first problem is why is there this 8 second delay? During these 8 seconds, logcat shows that `doInBackground` is being executed. However, according to logcat (this is the second problem) onPostExecute is never called (and so Dialog.dismiss()) is never run.

Logcat shows that everything following `DownloadCalendarTask().execute().get()` is being executed, so it's as if `onPostExecute` has just been skipped.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling AsyncTask.get() which causes the UI thread to be blocked while the AsyncTask is executing.

```
new DownloadCalendarTask().execute().get();
```

If you remove the call to get() it will perform asynchronously and give the expected result.

```
new DownloadCalendarTask().execute();
```

Edit:
You will also need to update the parameters to your onPostExecute method, they need to include the result. e.g.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. But if I remove get() is there still an easy way to retrieve the result of the AysncTask?

Comment: The simplest way to retrieve the result is to make the AsyncTask an inner class of your Activity, and then from the onPostExecute method call a method on your Activity to pass the activity the result.

Comment: I've made this change and the ProgressDialog now appears straight away, but now the code in doInBackgroundAction is executed and it reaches the end to the return statement, but then it seems to do nothing, and the progressdialog never ends. Again, onPostExecute is never called

Comment: I missed that you had a problem with your onPostExecute, you need to add the result as a parameter, I've updated my answer with the syntax for it. Probably worth having a skim over the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if you haven't already done so